# how to print this kind of pattern using swift 3?

Tags: swift3

i want to print like this output

```
    1
   121
  12312
 1234123
123454321
```

and here is my code

```
var no = 1
var numberOfRow = 5
for i in 1...numberOfRow {
    for _ in 1..<(6-i) {
        print("_", terminator: " ")
    }
    for _ in 1...i {
        //no += 1
        print("\(no)", terminator: " ")
        no += 1
    }
    for _ in 1..<no - 1 {
        no -= 1
        print("\(no - 1)", terminator: " ")
    }
    print("\(no)")
}
```

but its output shows that like bellow

```
_ _ _ _ 1 2
_ _ _ 2 3 2 1 2
_ _ 2 3 4 3 2 1 2
_ 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 2
2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 2
```

where is my problem in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this :

```
var no = 1
var numberOfRow = 5
for i in 1...numberOfRow {
    for _ in 1..<(6-i) {
        print(" ", terminator: " ")
    }
    for j in 1...i {
        print("\(j)", terminator: " ")
        no = j
    }
    for k in 1..<no {
        no -= 1
        print("\(no)", terminator: " ")
    }
    print(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the pseudo-code for you. change your for loops accordingly.

```
         int rc = 5;
        for(int i=1;i<=rc;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<(rc-i);j++)
            {
               Print("_");
            }
            for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
            {
                Print(k + 1);
            }
            for(int l=(i-1);l>0;l--)
            {
               Print(l);
            }
            print("\(no)")
        }
```